# sort GCP billing data by metadata tags

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, google-cloud-storage, metadata, google-cloud-billing

I'm a little confused in GCP with *tags*, *labels* and *metadata* and I do not find how to sort my billing informations by the metadata tags i set for every objects in the storage.
I have added a metadata tagging process which gives the id of the account that uploads a file through *signed url headers* or through *blobs* uploads. Then I launch requests on the billing with *big query*.
...but I do not see my tags in the *"labels"* field of the exports
How can I enable metadata tags sorting on billing exports ?

Thank you for your help

Comment: It's not clear what it is you are trying to report on.

Comment: It's not clear what it is you are trying to report on.

Are you trying to report on all GCP service consumption? Compute / SQL / GCS , that sort of stuff?
( then use labels, not metadata, and not tags )

Or are you trying to report on the cost of what is stored in a bucket?

You are billed for how much the bucket stores, not on how much storage each object in the bucket consumes.

Answer (score 0):

[Metadata identifies properties of the object, as well as specifies how the object should be handled when it's accessed. Metadata exists as key:value pairs. Metadata has fixed-key metadata, also Custom metadata, that is to say you can add any key:value value in your metadata.](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/metadata#introduction)

[If a group of GCP resources has the same key:value in its custom mateadata, who can take this key:value as the Bucket labels are key:value that allow you to group your buckets along with other Google Cloud resources such as virtual machine instances and persistent disks.](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/key-terms#bucket-labels)

[Tagging actually is like a condition, for example, I want to query those resources which have a specific key:value, then the service will look for those resources which have a label the same as key value.](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/xml-api/reference-headers#tagging)

May the explanation is still not easy to understand, let me use sql query as an example.

SELECT GCP.Resources.Cost FROM GCP.Resources WHERE GCP.Resources.Lable = Tag GROUP BY GCP.Resources.Metadata

Comment: Thus there is no way to use metadata in billing reports. The granularity for labels is bucket level but not the objects it contains. Am I wrong ?

Comment: it seems your understanding is correct, but be more specific what is your exact concern? please give a specific example. I will try to help explain it.

Comment: The idea is to tag the file with the id of the user that uploads a file so i can have a sorting of the cost of my storage by users.

Answer (score 0):

GCP billing doesn't break down Bucket costs by object.

It simply tells you how much the whole bucket cost you.

If you want to calculate what portion of your Bucket bill can be attributed to an object you will need to know when the object was uploaded and how big it was, and then do math to calculate the portion of the cost it's responsible for.

You would need to turn on logging on the buck to get that data.

Answer (score 0):

Tags data is available in both the Standard usage cost export and the Detailed usage cost export

```
SELECT
  invoice.month AS invoice_month,
  tag.value AS cost_center,
  ROUND((SUM(CAST(cost AS NUMERIC))
    + SUM(IFNULL((SELECT SUM (CAST(c.amount AS NUMERIC))
                  FROM UNNEST(credits) AS c), 0))), 2)
    AS net_cost
FROM `ivory-vim-309221.billing_export_dataset.gcp_billing_export_resource_v1_018ADD_3CEBBB_A4DF22`, UNNEST(tags) AS tag
WHERE tag.key = "cost_center" AND tag.namespace = "821092389413"
GROUP BY invoice.month, tag.value
ORDER BY invoice.month, tag.value;
```

https://cloud.google.com/billing/docs/how-to/export-data-bigquery-tables/standard-usage#tags